# Is google or tools available for jdk 8?

Tags: or-tools

I have to use JDK 8 for a project and want to give google OR Tools a try, which I included as jar library. When I ran the program it said, that my jdk is to old. Is google or tools also available for jdk 8?

Answer (score 0):

well you can rebuild it from source with any jdk.

Just setup your `JAVA_HOME` env

ps: personnaly I use open jdk 8